# Laravel - share functionality between multiple separate codebases

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

So I have a project here that consists of several websites, and rather than writing functionality such as a login flow and signup flow into each project codebase I’m looking for a way to write these shared components once and include them as dependencies into all of the required codebases.

The login flow, for example, consists of:

- model,
- view
- controller
- repository
- JavaScript
- css
- unit tests
- database migrations
- all other code related to the login flow

I would really like to be able to just include these shared functionalities via composer for example. Is there a way to do this?

Docker community edition, Laradock, Laravel 5.7, PHP 7.2, composer.

Comment: Aren't you just describing the purpose of packages or frameworks?  Laravel already handles a lot of the redundant setup of projects for you.

Comment: create a repo that is all the common code and pull it in to each website with composer like other vendor dependencies

Answer (score 0):

if you need to Share function you can make this function in helper function then put path in autoload path [this link will help you for more understand](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers)

Comment: This is not a self-contained answer. Your answer should not primarily be a link to external information.